# Python dict.get returns 0 evaluated as false

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, boolean

I use `dict.get()` in conditional statements to check if something exists in user-defined dictionaries (typically coming from yaml or json config files). This has worked pretty well for me, but I have this edge case:

```py
my_dict = {
    'my_key': 0.0
}

if my_dict.get('my_key'):
    # do some stuff
```

Here, `'my_key'` does exist in the dictionary, so `get` will not return None. However, because 0.0 is treated as `False` in conditionals, this does not work the way that it does in most cases. I can fix with this:

```py
if my_dict.get('my_key') is not None:
    # do some stuff
```

but this seems a bit verbose to me. For one conditional, it's not a big deal, but stringing together multiple conditionals can quickly become a little annoying.

My question is simply: is there a less verbose way to do this?

Comment: `if 'my_key' in my_dict:`

Comment: Look at Truthy and Falsy values in python for better understanding.

Comment: I think you're stuck with it. Depending on what you are doing in the conditional (and in this case you are pulling configuration) sometimes having a default is sufficent: `my_key = dict.get("my_key", 1.0)` - removing the need for the conditional completely.

Comment: The closing is right. As it relates to my intended use, I just need 'my_key' in my_dict, which is answered in the linked post. I searched SO for it, but didn't use the right language so I didn't find it. Thanks everyone for the time and attention to this!

Comment: @kederrac It's similar, but I think it's a gray area. I'd personally say it isn't a strict duplicate as the question is more about the problem of truthy values. However, since the answers to the other question also answer this one, it could be seen as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no less verbose to do it with `.get()`. All zero-valued numbers, empty sequences or `None` will be evaluated to `False`. If you want to differentiate between them, you'll have to explicitly check for `None`.

But as @mingaleg mentioned in the comments. If you're only using it to check if the key is in the dictionary, you could use `if 'my_key' in my_dict:`